Multi Tenant Docker App with a Authentication Server and APIs
Hi I am working on a web project and my current stack is as follows.
I have nginx for http server, nextjs for frontend and django as backend. Simple stuff.
Where you can register a company and each company can have multiple users.
As the project grew I wanted to instead of having a kitchen sink sort of backend app where there is one DB and all the users and companies are in it. I want to separate them but I am also going to dockerize  so each tenant will have a docker app and a docker postgres for that docker app. I am also going to create another djano app just to register the tenants so that I can book keep.
So it will look like below
--NGINX

 --domain1.app
 --domain1.db

 --domain2.app
 --domain2.db

 --domain-registeration-app 

 --frontend-nextjs-app

domain-registeration-app app book keeps all the tenants and forks new docker instances for a new tenant and maybe handles payments for each tenant.
Now comes the issue. This would work if a user is only in one tenant and will likely remember the subdomain for the tenant and can go to that tenants app by typing tenant1.myapp.com in urk and nginx would route that to request to matching subdomain docker to handle the requests.
But in my instance a User can ne a a member of multiple tenants(and do not think tenants as company like google,shell, netflix or whatever where user would NOT be apart of multiple tenants unless he/she was probably a corporate spy :)
Think tenants maybe like a gym or something else where this scenario is more plausible.
So user would have to remember all the subdomains (what if he/she is in 20 domains) and where he or she has to login.
Ideally when you log in you should get all the domains you are a member of(
But since the users are domain specific ( meaning each app has its own user table for security) you can not really query all the domains unless you do some crazy multicast like request to all the apps and see which ones responds 200  and you can list the domains where user exist).
So naturally first thing comes to mind is to move the users table to domain-registeration-app where tenants are created and maintained.
But first thing that comes to mind is how much of the common stuff do I need to move to domain-registeration-app before that turns to a kitchen sink as well. (but this is easy to solve)
But most importantly how what kind of authentication mechanism would you follow.
I though when a new tenant is created (lets call tenant1) a in domain-registeration-app we can create a secret key for that tenant1 which is stored in .tenant1.local.env and both domain-registeration-app and tenant1.app which is just created can use the same secret. domain-registeration-app creates a new JWT which can also be used by tenant1.app. So when domain-registeration-app responds the jwt to frontend, user can send data now directly to tenant1.app using the same jwt created by domain-registeration-app
Important to note that each tenant will have its own secret under .tenat*.env.local
IS this safe. I even thought about routing all requests to domain-registeration-app since users are there as an entry point(kind a like a reverse proxy like nginx, so a reverse proxy in a reverseproxy/router) no matter what and these request would be forwarded to the right "tenant" I know this is crazy and wasteful.
Hope this makes sense.

I've previously worked on products where there is a single multi-tenant instance, and it avoids basically all of the complexity you describe here where it's very expensive to onboard a new user and very expensive to keep infrastructure around for idle users.  (At the cost of needing to be very very careful, every time you access any data, that it's correctly customer-scoped.)  I'd be inclined to stick with your existing working setup.
